# TYPO3 extension - linking properties of related classes?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have the following question about TYPO3 extension developement(using extension builder):

For simplicity reasons I only take 2 classes in that example. One class is customer another is appliance. The relations are set in extension builder (it's 1:n). Creating a record/object of appliance in the TYPO3 backend (Folder(List)) not only let's me choose the properties of the appliance record, but also lets me choose an object of "customer" in a select drop down menu at the bottom.

Now I have a property called customer ID in the class appliance. Of cause this property is related to the property of the same name of its related object customer. I not only want to make this property unchangable in the backend by the backend user directly, but i also want to set it while choosing the related object of customer at the bottom. Or rather: I want the property customerID somehow to be linked to the related object of customer or rather the property customerID of customer.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is your customer id coming from another system and has to have specific values? Because otherwise I'd suggest to just drop that field an use the regular UID field for it. Typo3 automatically maps relations to the Uid, so that'd save you some work.